Ubuntu Studio 24.04 – no sound after install
I installed Ubuntu Studio using the Ubuntu Studio Installer as described on their page and got no sound at all after rebooting. Neither the built-in notebook speakers, nor the (connected) bluetooth device are shown under settings and do not play sound at all.
As per their own documentation their should be a tool called “Ubuntu Studio Audio Configuration” which does not exist in the app search. Also the alternativly mentioned tool ubuntustudio-pipewire-config is not installed and also not available via the package manager (apt).
This is a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio over an existing Ubuntu Desktop and sound worked before via built-in speakers or headphones. I cannot find any documentation on how to proceed here; does anyone has a useful tip on how to successfully finish an Ubuntu Studio install to get audio output working (again)?

Ubuntu version?

Current one; 24.04. Fixed that only by completely re-installing the whole system and using the Ubuntu Studio 24.04 ISO directly instead of trying to use the Ubuntu Studio Installer over an existing Ubuntu installation. Still not sure what the problem was. (Maybe the Ubuntu Studio Installer does have a problem.)
